# how to restrict pipeline deployment by user?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

how can I restrict certain Jenkins users from deploying to certain environments in my Pipeline?

I have my pipeline and you can select to which environment (server) you want to deploy the code, but what I want to achieve is to have only a certain group of users to be able to deploy to Production, for obvious security issues, especially without blocking the other users from deploying to any other environment

right now, my pipeline works but anyone can trigger a deploy to any environment

the only thing I found is to block the entire project via user management, but it's not quite what I want to achieve.

what I want to achieve is to have

User1 and User2 be able to deploy to production, but User3 can't trigger a Prod deployment, or at least group them and allow Group A to deploy and Group B to not deploy to Prod

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me is to insert manual approval into pipeline which can be passed only by member of certain group. I have jenkins integrated with AD but it should work for other types of groups as well:

```
    def checkEnvPermissions() {
        if (env.ENVIRONMENT == "production") {
            userInput = input message: 'Is this deployment approved?', ok: '', submitter: 'AD_GROUP_WITH_PERMISSIONS', parameters: [
                [$class: 'hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: 'Approved\nNot Approved', name: 'isApproved', description: 'This input can only be answered by users with deployment permission on this environment']
            ]
            if (userInput == "Not Approved") {
                error "Deployment to PROD is not approved"
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't consider asking extra questions as an option it is possible to do something like this:

```
def listOfGroupsAllowedToDeploy = ["group1","group2"]
def userId = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
def user = hudson.model.User.getById(userId, false)
userAuthorities = user.getAuthorities()
if userAuthorities.intersect(listOfGroupsAllowedToDeploy)
```